# Java: Transposing a SpringLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, springlayout

I've got a SpringLayout that I need to transpose.

Basically, when you create a SpringLayout it fills out the panel by columns, so that if you have

```
JPanel temp = new JPanel()
retCase2.add(label = new JLabel("A"));
retCase2.add(label = new JLabel("B"));
retCase2.add(label = new JLabel("C"));
retCase2.add(label = new JLabel("D"));

Utils.makeCompactGrid(retCase2,
2, 2, //rows, cols
1, 1,        //initX, initY
10, 10);
```

The result is a table that looks like this:

```
A B
C D
```

However, I want

```
A C
B D
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Beside first adding label C and afterwards add label B ?

Comment: Yep. Each row is being read in from an array, which means that if I can transpose it, I'll only need one for loop. Otherwise, I'll need 84 for loops (that's the number of rows I actually have). It's not an urgent question of anything. Just the kind of question that feels like it should have an easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just switch the order of the "b" and "c"